# Lexik JWT login successfull but returns 401 Unauthorized from other routes

Tags: api, rest

I am using LexikJWTBundle for a RESTful API.

Login works and I get my token. But when I make a GET or a POST request I get a 401 answer. {"code":401,"message":"You are not authenticated","errors":null}

The Authorization header seems ok since I get in the profiler:

Authorization
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NDQ5MDEzODAsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoibGV0YWwxNjA5IiwiaXAiOiIxOTIuMTY4LjQwLjExMyIsImlhdCI6IjE0NDQ4MTQ5ODAifQ
.clSN7xxXT9r9TaVAAp6a7ybMQYOS7M6tfl96xKf-RpeXhZ0Lze7TdIGVarTu0bKKzt3FurG7QCgJsaNT7vEymEWc0E5JYABkeBm
rCp1pjKEaxIq2JmWxGJfV8FZ5a8V0mJIGO-nEsvJNL3rOIGV8ykeAwa6jNzqS_bHgmcAqQRBB4hc-h3YOAf9zBcHoarVZbNGkEiZ
7v6y_K1JqOPzSP0WufXoD2soBgZkrhE2MmDhaDo-r2hKnjomgB2_siembqJcZ1S2ECBwZjZvA1sRXJOjQs55cIlHoyzeEeQbsfE4
yrlDNxmeB07Lh-MRAehJV45cXux7Swi2qNEyiPe_hBXDN6D0Fk5NoVlN09sWaqObu3L2MEJswKr8a2bWPQnoPTZBWieugH-Oxzas
dHhsrAvLDCIvEDhMmI8bLMiCHqpXqR2hEkYjMEecNiKIeBgMlvqjmQs8OrjM40HlMsriAXIPoXKpVwNCiVk4AOF7zKX1TFS6bOX9
tuqJF9B2Fz9JVmFzUW6fFotl7Ef0lQ8ccZ-Vf2roImhMRUBUSP_9AqYzssRviKBOOMYCQxCDUToBxOtgc_1M6Hm4H4gHdUXHNUPa
QscvOqSGmLg7HeMP7FsXYd9OPUSVxbbGwmM8LB41cfitwyELAyw-J2P7xSs2lUItvDyLzVzYV0QUSX0TQGH4

My secuyrity.yml

security:
    encoders:
        MobileApiBundle\Entity\Abonne: 
            algorithm: md5
            encode-as-base64: false
            iterations: 1

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

providers:
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: MobileApiBundle:Abonne
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/api-mobile/(_(profiler|wdt|doc))/
        security: false

    mail:
        pattern: ^/api-mobile/mails
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        security: false
        provider: user_provider

    login:
        pattern:  ^/api-mobile/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        provider: user_provider
        form_login:
            check_path: /api-mobile/login_check
            require_previous_session: false
            username_parameter: _username
            password_parameter: _password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api-mobile
        stateless: true
        provider: user_provider
        lexik_jwt:
            authorization_header:
                enabled: true
                prefix:  Bearer
            create_entry_point:  true
            query_parameter:
                enabled: true
                name:    bearer



access_control:
    - { path: ^/api-mobile/mails, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api-mobile/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api-mobile, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
```

Comment: I have resolved my issue by using the symfony web server instead of my local webserver

Comment: You should create an answer and accept it, it can be helpful for other with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by using the symfony web server instead of my local webserver